# I need to subtract from the input

Tags: python, math, subtraction

I need to subtract 60 from the input before it divdes the bottom 3 lines in my code.

Thanks

I don't know much about coding i have tried some things but they don't work

```
income = float(input("Income: "))

print("Savings: " + str(income*0.74))
print("Spending: " + str(income*0.24))
print("Test: " + str(income*0.02))
```

I need to subtract 60 from the input before it divdes the bottom 3 lines in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
income = float(input("Income: ")) - 60
```

By the way, StackOverflow, as far as I can see, is not a place for beginner questions like this one. Don't be too disappointed if you'll be down-voted by some users. I know it can be harsh on the mood. Stay positive, learning to code is a tough but superb endeavor and totally worth it. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks wmax, income = float(input("Income: ")) - 60 did work

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at tutorials before anything. This will help you get the basics and achieve most of what you want by yourself. Have a look at [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) for a list of tutorials to start with. It should not take you long before you can do basic stuff.

Anyway if you want the quick answer (but you should not take it as granted, it's better to understand than to copy paste) :

```
income -= 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
income = income - 60
income -= 60
```

There are loads of tutorials out there including videos on YouTube.
[click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) for a more in depth explanation on different operations that can be performed.

Subtracting 60 from the stored value of income and making income the new value.

Hope this helps